# Clion use different colour schemes for text and background

Tags: clion

I'm a big fan of the Foundation Dark colour scheme however I much prefer the text colours used by Nord. I would therefore, like to use the Nord theme to highlight text but the Foundation Dark scheme for everything else.

[image]

Could you please let me know how to do this? Thanks,

Comment: Seems that 
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10321-nord
can be a good choice.

Comment: @uta I'm not sure what you're suggesting. I am already using Nord, I would just like to change the background colour to that from foundation.

Comment: Seems you need to make the hybrid schema manually. Or find an alternative at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?tags=Theme

Comment: The colour schema can be exported as XML so the the creation of hybrid can be a merge process with any diff tool.